# Imprimir todas as páginas de um arquivo PDF

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf

Gostaria de saber se é possível imprimir todas as páginas de um arquivo PDF obtido de uma base de dados (BLOB). Esta base de dados possui aquivos de imagem e PDF, logo a página de exibição mostrará ambos os formatos.

Segue o trecho do código:

```
echo '<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,'.base64_encode($row["pdf"]).'" type="application/pdf" style="height:1200px;width:100%"></object>';
```

Quando mando imprimir (pressionando CTRL+P) só imprimi a última página do documento PDF.

Desde já, agradeço!

Comment: Mas na tela (HTML) exibe todo o PDF?

Comment: Outra pergunta. O problema acontece em todos os browsers ou algum em específico?

Comment: A aplicação funciona apenas no Firefox. Nele são exibidas as imagens e os PDF (por completo) obtidos de um banco de dados SQL (guardados como BLOB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> só executa para o DOCUMENTO HTML, para imprimir a partir do OBJECT terá que o programa/plugin usado no OBJECT mesmo fazer a impressão, e lembre-se cada navegador implementa a sua solução de PDF, sendo esta solução parte do navegador ou não, muitas vezes é parte do AdobeReader ou FoxitReader e não do navegador, apesar de algumas coisas estarem mudando, no entanto vale lembrar que o comando básico (aceito em alguns plugins/programas) seria apontar o print para o element, assim:

```js
var meuPdf = document.getElementById("meuPdf");

document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function () {
   meuPdf.print();
};
```

```html
<object id="meuPdf" data="data:application/pdf;base64,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" type="application/pdf"></object>

<button id="btnPrint">Imprimir</button>
```

O que realmente não garanto ser compatível com diferentes programas/plugins e browsers (depois irei enumerar os testes, mas existem muitas variações de navegadores e mobiles).

---

### Print.js

O https://printjs.crabbly.com/ é uma lib inicialmente projetada para imprimir PDFs (hoje faz mais que isso), ela pode lhe ajudar, mas já vou lhe adiantando, nada é 100% garantido, então primeiro coloque isto em seu site (o copie os arquivos e embarque diretamente do seu site):

```
<script src="https://printjs-4de6.kxcdn.com/print.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://printjs-4de6.kxcdn.com/print.min.css">
```

E então execute assim:

```
<button type="button" onclick="printJS('local/do/seu/pdf.pdf')">
    Imprimir PDF
</button>
```

Eu realmente não sei afirmar se funcionará com o **data URI scheme**, mas já lhe adianto, apesar da lib funcionar bem no Chrome, no Firefox não funcionou, isso é porque foi o que eu já disse e reforço:

> Cada navegador implementa a sua própria solução para PDF, não existe uma solução padrão para tudo e provavelmente em alguns navegadores ou sistemas operacionais, como mobiles, é provável que nada disto funcione.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Guilherme! Desculpe-me por não explicar direito. Essa página HTML exibe um relatório com arquivos de imagens e PDF. Eu preciso imprimi-lo por completo (imagens e PDFs)... Já tentei colocar tudo em PDF, mas o DomPDF deu erro quando fiz a junção de dois PDF (versões mais novas).